# Group keys when values are equals in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to group people based on there preferences in spark/python. After many transformations from the original data my final RDD is:

```
key value
h1->[1,2]
h1->[1,3]
h1->[1,4]
h1->[2,3]
h3->[1,4]
```

Now my transformed RDD should be like

```
[h1,h3]->[1,4]
```

Which says me that person h1 and h3 have same set of interests.

How can I achieve this?

My Intermediate data looks like:

```
   [((u'90249', u'79727', u'49495'), [u'Collecting Sports Cards (Baseball', u' Basketball', u' Football', u' Hockey)']), 
    ((u'79727', u'12512', u'71917'), [u'Collecting Sports Cards (Baseball', u' Basketball', u' Football', u' Hockey)']), 
    ((u'12512', u'27195', u'49495'), [u'Collecting Sports Cards (Baseball', u' Basketball', u' Football', u' Hockey)']), 
    ((u'90249', u'76176', u'49495'), [u'Collecting Sports Cards (Baseball', u' Basketball', u' Football', u' Hockey)']), 
    ((u'79727', u'27195', u'76176'), [u'Collecting Sports Cards (Baseball', u' Basketball', u' Football', u' Hockey)'])]
```

The above is the RDD produced in the intermediate transformation. I am surprised to see the results and now I am facing issues in combing to form the final RDD.

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: do you want match the full set of interest? not the partial matches? if yes, you can make set of interests as a key and persons as a value. In this case you  can use `reduceByKey` and will get all the persons which have exactly same set of interests for each unique set of interests.

Comment: rdd.map(lambda (a,b):(b,a)).groupByKey().reduceByKey(lambda v,k:[v+k]).take(5)

Comment: My reduceBykey needed some change for the desired ouput. Can you please find it.

Comment: try `rdd.mapValues(str).map(lambda (x,y): (y,x)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).filter(lambda (x,y): len(y)>2).collect()`

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Error caused

Comment: can you explain your intermediate result , looks different than your first example.